# como adaptar codigo propio appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator

Estoy haciendo un proyecto classic en `appcelerator` y quiero cambiar este fragmento de codigo para que funcione en appcelerator:

```
"document.getElementById('imagen').style.transform = 'rotate(' + grados + 'deg)';
```

Comment: de que lenguaje viene ese fragmento de código?

Comment: es javascript, quiero hacer girar una imagen los grados que introduzca en un campo de texto.

Comment: es javascript, quiero  girar una imagen los grados que meta en un campo de texto, puse limite  entre dos cifras. si no es la correcta me de un alert avisando el error.  intruducidos.  tengo este codigo pero no muevo imagen lo que introducco  :button.addEventListener('click',function(){
 var matriz =Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().rotate();
 image.animate({
  transform:matriz,
  duration:4000
 });
 var grados=tf.value;
 if (grados < -90 || grados > 90 || grados == '') {
                alert('El valor introducido no es válido, debes introducir cifra entre -90 y 90, gracias...');
            }